# Teradata SQL export to csv

Tags: teradata

Is there a way to run a Teradata SQL query and then export the data to an external file?

For example, if I ran:

```
SELECT TOP 10
  *
FROM
  mydb.mytable
```

Could I write this in such a way that it will export to a CSV?  Do I need to store my data in a temp table first and then do `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`?  Any ideas would be appreciated - I've been returning data to `R` and then exporting, but there's no need for the intermediate step in some jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` in Teradata.

The only tool capable of exporting CSV directly is TPT (Teradata Parallel Transporter).

Otherwise you have to do the concat in your query using `SELECT TRIM(col1) || ',' || TRIM(col2)...` and then export based on your client's capabilities.

Comment: Okay thanks, I saw the `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` on another site, glad to know it's not an option.  I'll look into TPT, thank you.